# Use of Azure AD credential SQL VM

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

I have SQL Server 2019 running on an Azure VM (Windows Server 2019). The client wants to use Azure AD groups and users to provide access to the database, but does not have AD DS installed on a VM.

Is it possible to run the

```
CREATE USER [MySqlUser] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

on a SQL Server running on an Azure VM to add users from the AD tenant?

Can it be joined to an Azure AD without running AD DS so I can run the command above?

Comment: AFAIK none of the non-PaaS SQL Server editions support AAD authentication as an authentication type. They only support SQL and windows. The way this is usually done is you set up your windows AD as required, and use that to authentication to SQL Server. Your AD is replicated to AAD to support single sign on scenarios. Seriously consider moving to a PaaS edition of SQL Server if you want to use AAD authentication

Comment: Yea I would typically agree with trying to use Azure SQL Server, but, in this case, we are building a data warehouse on a budget ; )  Azure SQL Server always uses Full recovery model and we do quite a bit of bulk operations which greatly benefit from a simple recovery model...hence why we are trying to go a SQL VM route so we can control recovery model along with how many physical disks we can spread across TempDB and real database...was just hoping there was a way to use AAD authentication as well, but as I guess we would need AD DS services enabled.

Comment: I suggest you investigate Azure SQL Hyperscale. All those things you mention... are probably not an issue in Hyperscale and there's a whole load of things you don't have to worry about. Do the volumes you are processing really warrant all that low level tuning? In Hyperscale you can scale up to 8 vCores for an hour then scale back down to 2 vCores. I've built many datawarehouses in Azure SQL PaaS in various editions and depending on your real volumes, none of these things are an issue

Comment: I have to reiterate, if you have a AAD-only cloud facing customer, you really need to avoid IaaS solutions, and the reasoning you have given may not take into account some newer PaaS capabilities.

Comment: You are correct, they are not an isue, but it's really about cost.  HyperScale is great, but very pricy compared to SQL VM.  The client will have to understand the trade off between complexity of configuring a SQL VM (which is really handled nicely through ARM templates) and cost of a fully managed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a the answer of Microsoft MSFT that may be helpful for you:

Please find the explanation of different scenarios as following.

- You can connect your on-premise environment using [site-to-site VPN to
  Azure VNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) which the SQL azure VM is part of .
- Alternatively you do not have an on-premise environment at all and
  are a cloud only company who have created a standalone SQL server on
  Azure VM , then you cannot directly join the machine to Azure AD
  instance and hence you can not have Azure AD users logging in to the
  SQL VM using their Userprinciplename (the logon id for a azure ad
  user.) . However if you enable Azure AD domain services for your
  azure AD tenant, you can then connect the Azure VM to the same subnet
  as Azure AD domain services and then [join it to the Azure AD domain
  services instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm). Your [users in azure AD will be synced to your
  azure AD domain services instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization) and the same user account can be
  used to logon to the Azure VM.

For more details, please ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cee70d52-bd57-472d-b97e-6fd71f76dfbb/how-to-join-azure-vm-to-azure-ad

Comment: That's very interesting, I learnt something new today. I still wonder what authentication method you would use. I guess you'd need to log into the Azure VM with your AAD credentials, then in SSMS on the VM, log into SQL using window authentication?? It sounds a bit far fetched to work, it would be awesome if someone could test it for me!